# ERROR: ORA- 00933

Tags: oracle

IS there a reason why i keep getting this error ? 
Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
 (State:S1000, Native Code: 3A5)

For this code

```
            SELECT DAY_DATE,
       whse_prod_vendor_nbr,
       PLN_NBR,
        SUM(STOREIOH) "STORE IOH",
        SUM(DCIOH) "DC IOH",
        SUM(DCOO) "DC OO"
FROM (SELECT day_date, whse_prod_vendor_nbr, PLN_NBR, SUM(a.LO_IOH_UNITS) "STOREIOH"
        FROM  MSS_OWNER.FCT_IOH_DAY_STR_PLN a, dim_prod_pln b, dim_period c, dim_location d
        WHERE a.prod_id = b.prod_id
        AND a.per_id = c.per_id
        AND a.loc_id = d.str_nbr
        GROUP BY day_date, whse_prod_vendor_nbr, PLN_NBR
        HAVING SUM(a.LO_IOH_UNITS) > 0) AS STORE

        INNER JOIN (SELECT DAY_DATE, whse_prod_vendor_nbr, pln_nbr, SUM(a.TOT_REG_IOH_UNITS + a.TOT_DISTR_IOH_UNITS) "DCIOH", SUM(a.TOT_REG_ordr_UNITS + a.TOT_DISTR_ordr_UNITS) "DCOO"
                        FROM MSS_OWNER.FCT_DA_DAY_DC_VEND_WIC a, dim_prod_wic b, dim_period c
                        WHERE a.PROD_ID = b.PROD_ID
                        AND a.PER_ID = c.PER_ID
                        GROUP BY DAY_DATE, whse_prod_vendor_nbr, PLN_NBR
                        HAVING SUM(a.TOT_REG_IOH_UNITS + a.TOT_DISTR_IOH_UNITS) > 0) AS DC
        ON STORE.PLN_NBR = DC.PLN_NBR
        AND STORE.DAY_DATE = DC.DAY_DATE

     Where DAY_DATE >= to_date ('1/26/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY') --- ENTER THE DATE
     AND DAY_DATE <= to_date('1/26/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY') --- ENTER THE SAME DATE OR A RANGE
     and PLN_NBR in ('40000278132')
     --AND b.whse_prod_vendor_nbr in

     GROUP BY DAY_DATE, whse_prod_vendor_nbr, PLN_NBR;
```

Comment: You do have a `;` on the end right?

Comment: Yes, I do and I still get the same error

Comment: Chelsea - what do you use to work with your database? SQL Developer? Toad? SQL\*Plus? Something else? Pretty much any of these environments tell you exactly **where** the error occurred. Or are you only interacting through some "intermediate" third-party application? In any case, if you use Oracle often enough, you may benefit from learning to use SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer (both free!) so you can run your queries directly against the DB and benefit from their features.

Answer (score 0):

whitespace missing before alias in line 7?

```
FROM (SELECT day_date, whse_prod_vendor_nbr, PLN_NBR, SUM(a.LO_IOH_UNITS) "STOREIOH"
```

another thing is

```
AND (STOREIOH) > 0
```

this should be

```
having SUM(a.LO_IOH_UNITS) > 0
```

the same problem of using sum in where clause is with second subquery. And one more problem with `AS` used in subquery alias. Try that:

```
    SELECT DAY_DATE,
       whse_prod_vendor_nbr,
       PLN_NBR,
        SUM(STOREIOH) "STORE IOH",
        SUM(DCIOH) "DC IOH",
        SUM(DCOO) "DC OO"
FROM (SELECT day_date, whse_prod_vendor_nbr, PLN_NBR, SUM(a.LO_IOH_UNITS) "STOREIOH"
        FROM  MSS_OWNER.FCT_IOH_DAY_STR_PLN a, dim_prod_pln b, dim_period c, dim_location d
        WHERE a.prod_id = b.prod_id
        AND a.per_id = c.per_id
        AND a.loc_id = d.str_nbr
        GROUP BY day_date, whse_prod_vendor_nbr, PLN_NBR
        HAVING SUM(a.LO_IOH_UNITS) > 0)  STORE

        INNER JOIN (SELECT DAY_DATE, whse_prod_vendor_nbr, pln_nbr, SUM(a.TOT_REG_IOH_UNITS + a.TOT_DISTR_IOH_UNITS) "DCIOH", SUM(a.TOT_REG_ordr_UNITS + a.TOT_DISTR_ordr_UNITS) "DCOO"
                        FROM MSS_OWNER.FCT_DA_DAY_DC_VEND_WIC a, dim_prod_wic b, dim_period c
                        WHERE a.PROD_ID = b.PROD_ID
                        AND a.PER_ID = c.PER_ID
                        GROUP BY DAY_DATE, whse_prod_vendor_nbr, PLN_NBR
                        HAVING SUM(a.TOT_REG_IOH_UNITS + a.TOT_DISTR_IOH_UNITS) > 0)  DC
        ON STORE.PLN_NBR = DC.PLN_NBR
        AND STORE.DAY_DATE = DC.DAY_DATE

     Where DAY_DATE >= to_date ('1/26/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY') --- ENTER THE DATE
     AND DAY_DATE <= to_date('1/26/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY') --- ENTER THE SAME DATE OR A RANGE
     and PLN_NBR in ('40000278132')
     --AND b.whse_prod_vendor_nbr in

     GROUP BY DAY_DATE, whse_prod_vendor_nbr, PLN_NBR
```

Comment: Even with those changes I still get - Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
 (State:S1000, Native Code: 3A5)

Comment: @ChelseaWeber remove `AS` in aliases of tables. `AS` is optional for column alias but not allowed for table alias.

Comment: THAT WORKS ! . THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: :-)  The right answer is in a comment, not in the answer.  The first thing that SQL Developer pointed to is the `AS` before the alias for the subquery. It would be best to move that from the comment to the answer itself (perhaps add an **Edit** at the top of the answer) for future visitors to this thread. Anyway, +1 because the answer with comments is indeed correct.